# Vue3 Router with Typescript: missing RouteConfig

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I created a new vue project from @vue/cli `$> vue create my-project`, activated the Typescript option and router option, and upgraded to vue3 beta with `$>vue add vue-next`.

Now, `$>npm run serve` fails with

```
ERROR in /home/auser/dev/my-project/src/router/index.ts(1,10):
1:10 Module '"../../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router"' has no exported member 'RouteConfig'.

  > 1 | import { RouteConfig, createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
      |          ^
    2 | import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
```

The entire file is not that long, and RouteConfig is used later on:

```js
//index.ts
import { RouteConfig, createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/about',
  name: 'About',
  // route level code-splitting
  // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
  // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
}
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

**Q**: What is the correct type of RouteConfig, which I need for `createRouter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Since this is pre-release: I am using vue-router@4.0.0-alpha.13.)

I ran into the same thing. The correct type for routes array is `RouteRecordRaw` according to the view-router.d.ts; `RouteConfig` is for the createRouter argument itself.

But if I typed the array as `RouteRecordRaw` then i ran into the problem of `RouteRecordRaw` definition is composed of several others types that look like they are not exported, so typing the array causes more problems than it solves.

I suspect that a better pattern will emerge, but for the moment I typed the routes array as `any`, which works.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the problem. However I keep having problems with vue3 + ts, so I'm switching back to vue2 (maybe with ts, let's see)

Comment: @Moritz Yesterday was the first time I was able to get a TS and Vue3+Router project to compile, but it is early days. I know that Evan You talks a lot about Vue3 supporting TS better than Vue2 so I am sure it will get easier.

Comment: Great! I hope the out-of-the-box support will become great with vue3. For now, I switched back to vue2, ultimately because I had another issue with my vue3 setup not supporting `<input type="list" ...` - I'm just in the phase of learning both vue and TS, so that's the way to go for me.

Answer (score 11):

you can use like this.

```
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: basicRoutes as RouteRecordRaw[]
});
```

Comment: Thank you! What's the type of the `component: Home as XYZ` then?